# Is it possible to create cornerRadius for Konva.Path

Tags: konvajs

I know it is possible to add cornerRadius to Konva.Rect, but is there a way to do same thing for Konva.Path? I've read docs, stackoverflow, but couldn't find any solution. Any idea would be great.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a Bezier curve ?  Konva path has a data() attribute via which you can pass in an SVG formatted path statement. Looking on [W3Schools explanation of SVG path](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp) you have a couple of curve options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `Konva.Path` doesn't support that. As you define your own path with `data` attribute, you have to define the corner radius logic by yourself.

You can only slightly round corners with `lineJoin: 'round'` setting https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Shape.html#lineJoin